# Find one prime $p = kn + r$ where $\gcd(r, n) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

If $r$ and $n$ are two integers such that $\gcd(r, n) = 1$ and $r < n$, how do I prove the existence of a prime $p$ such that $p \equiv r \bmod n$?

I have found that [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) ensures that an infinity of these primes exist. However, I can't exactly use it nor do I have the tools to prove it.

So is there a way with simpler math to prove the existence of such a prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is logically impossible unless you happen to know that $r$ is prime.

Suppose you had a theorem that establishes the existence of "just one" prime $p = kn+r$.  Since $r$ is not prime, surely $k \ge 1$.  Now apply your theorem to the pair $(r,mn)$ where $m$ is any integer greater than $k$ and relatively prime to $r$.  This new prime will be strictly greater than $p$ and still congruent to $r$ mod $n$.  Continuing in this fashion will give an infinite number of primes from "just one".

Comment: I see. I apologize for having poorly phrased my question. I don't actually want to prove that there is only one (which is as you say completely false). I would like to prove that there is one, but I don't need to prove there are an infinity. That is what I meant, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @liteplane No, I don’t think you read my answer carefully.  I understood your question just fine.  What I am saying is that if you can prove “just one” in generality then you can prove “infinitely many”.  Therefore it is impossible to avoid Dirichlet’s theorem.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't quite seen it that way ! The proofs I have found for that theorem use concepts that I don't know yet. I assume that if it were possible to prove what I asked with simple math there would be no need to use these concepts for the theorem.

Comment: @liteplane Well, there are some specific subcases of Dirichlet’s theorem that can be proved by alternative means, famously $r=1$ for any $n$.  However this uses some of the theory of cyclotomic polynomials and I’m not sure whether you would count that as simple math (I guess that depends largely on what concepts you have already learned).

Comment: Almost! It is funny that you would mention the cyclotomic polynomials as it is actually while trying to prove the irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials that I encountered this problem. So I guess I can't exactly use them yet. I'll just find another way, thanks for the help.